# Reload page in php

Tags: php, web

While designing sign up page I wish to reload page if user has submitted anything wrong in the fill up boxes. How can I reload page after the user presses submit button with a wrong entry ? (while verifying expected content through php)

Comment: header() with Location would be the common way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `header()` plus some `_GET` variables for telling the original page there were errors.

Form submit page:

```
<?php
   //.... lots of code validation
   if ($failed) {
      header('Location: http://path.com/to/your/site/original_form.php?error=1');
   }
?>
```

Form page:

```
<?php 
   if (isset($_GET['error']) {
      echo "there was an error! Please fix it!";
   }
?>
```

Comment: where is the redirect() function in the php manual ? (hint, it's not)

Comment: Oh my I apologize. I'm used to using it in CodeIgniter. Updated!

Comment: It's not wrong anymore... it's a tough crowd in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

```
if (validation_failed) {
    header("Location: http://yourserver.com/signup.php");
} else {
    header("Location: http://yourserver.com/welcome.php");
}
```

[PHP Header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: full URI for location please.